# azureupload fails for big files with error code 403 after an hour or so

Tags: azure, jenkins, upload

Using Jenkins 2.222.3 with plugin Windows Azure Storage 1.1.7

The azureupload works properly for small files. However for big files (my test was 12GB of data), upload fails after roughly an hour with the message below.

Uploading through a browser on Azure portal works without fail.

```
09:20:36  MicrosoftAzureStorage - Uploading files to Microsoft Azure  
10:21:22  ERROR: MicrosoftAzureStorage - Error occurred while uploading to Azure - <storage_account_id>  
10:21:22  com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.exceptions.WAStorageException: Fail to upload individual files to blob  
10:21:22    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.service.UploadToBlobService.uploadIndividuals(UploadToBlobService.java:151)  
10:21:22    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.service.UploadService.execute(UploadService.java:719)  
10:21:22    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.WAStoragePublisher.perform(WAStoragePublisher.java:438)  
10:21:22    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)  
10:21:22    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)  
10:21:22    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)  
10:21:22    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)  
10:21:22    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  
10:21:22    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
10:21:22    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  
10:21:23    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  

10:21:23  Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:   com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.exceptions.WAStorageException: Failed to upload test_upload/full.zip with error code 403  
10:21:23    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.service.UploadService$UploadOnSlave.invoke(UploadService.java:373)  
10:21:23    at com.microsoftopentechnologies.windowsazurestorage.service.UploadService$UploadOnSlave.invoke(UploadService.java:346)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code you are getting is 403. Http 403 means forbidden.

What may be happening is that your authentication token is expiring after 1 hour. Another alternative would be that it is related to the lease of the blob.

> Many Azure services have Jenkins plugins. Some of these plugins will
> be out of support as of February 29, 2024. Azure CLI is the currently
> recommended way to integrate Jenkins with Azure services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/azure-storage-blobs-as-build-artifact-repository

I would recommend that you upload the file using the Azure CLI instead of the pluggin.

Comment: Wouldn't the Azure CLI have the same problem with the auth token expiring after an hour ? I can't seem to find any information about this topic.

I'll try to implement the Azure CLI and see how it goes.

Comment: Using the CLI is both faster and do not cause the failing after 1 hour anymore. This seems to be the correct solution.